# jQuery 'iOS style' switch button needs draggable function

Tags: jquery, draggable, uiswitch

I have built an iOS style switch using jQuery, CSS and HTML.

At the moment it is triggered on click. I want to keep the click function but would also like the ability to drag it. Is this possible without a plugin and how would it be done.

Working Example without drag feature.
http://jsfiddle.net/buduR/5/

JS.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.element.switch').each(function(){
        $(this).css('width',($(this).find('li:first').width() + 40) + 'px');
        $(this).find('span').css('left',($(this).find('li:first').width() + 18) + 'px')
        $(this).find('li:last').css('left',($(this).find('li:first').width() + 30) + 'px').css('text-align','right');
        if($(this).find('li:first').attr('data-val') == $(this).find('input').val()){ $(this).find('ol').css('left',0); }
        else { $(this).find('ol').css('left','-' + ($(this).find('li:first').width() + 20) + 'px'); }
    });

    $('.element.switch').click(function(){
        if($(this).find('li:first').attr('data-val') == $(this).find('input').val()){
            $(this).find('ol').animate({left:- ($(this).find('li:first').width() + 20)},500);
            $(this).find('input').val($(this).find('li:last').attr('data-val'));
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('ol').animate({left:0},500);
            $(this).find('input').val($(this).find('li:first').attr('data-val'));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, jquery has its own dragabble pugin, but you need to use the jquery_ui.min

with this pice of code

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    cursor: "move",
    containment: "parent",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        // do stuff when you start drag
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        // do stuff when you finish drag
    }
});
```

you can make the class "drag" to be dragable, so if you had to your span the class="drag" then you just need to work the css

here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buduR/9/)

**EDIT**

I've updated the JsFiddle, now it loads the jquery.ui.touch-punch and it does work on IOS (in jsfiddle it doesn't because of the way  jsfiddle works, but outside it does).
Also I've added the containment option to the draggable so it now stays inside the ol.

Comment: if you change your css making the ol width:100% the draggable span fits perfectly in place, so now it is just a question of css

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery .draggable  is probably not going to work on ios , you can look into these:

Take a look at this: https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch

You could be interested in [jQuery Mobile](http://www.jquerymobile.com/) as well.

EDIT:

I don't know if I read your question right , if you just want to simulate ios style UI in a web browser , jquery  .draggable will work fine , but if you want it to function on mobil touch screens , use the links I provided

Comment: I believe he is trying just to simulate the IOS style

Comment: I was trying to do both. The drag gable feature needs to be restrained to the container width. I think I can manage to work out that. On iOs I suggest faking it. It already works onClick, what if we had it respond to a touch move slide left or right and then perform the appropriate animation currently assigned to click. Any idea how you detect a left swipe and a right swipe on an element?